# What am I missing from this DELETE statement

Tags: sql-delete

Here is the question that I'am having problems with:

Write a `DELETE` statement that deletes the row in the Categories table that has an ID of 44444. When you execute this statement, it will produce an error since the category has related rows in the Products table. To fix that, precede the DELETE statement with another `DELETE` statement that deletes all products in this category.

I don't know why I keep getting this error message:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK__Products__Catego__145C0A3F". The conflict occurred in database
>   "MyGuitarShop", table "dbo.Products", column 'CategoryID'.

And here is my SQL statement:

```
DELETE Categories
FROM Categories JOIN Products
    ON Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID
WHERE Categories.CategoryID = 44444;
```

I have been working on this for a while now and I can't figure out what im doing wrong and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What I found is you don't just use `JOIN`, but instead one of the following:

`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, `FULL JOIN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delete the products first, then you will be able to delete the category. You have the error because of a foreign key constraint.
Therefore I would write 2 queries:

```
DELETE FROM Products WHERE CategoryID = 44444;
```

Now as there are no products with this id the category can be deleted:

```
DELETE FROM Categories WHERE CategoryID = 44444;
```

Comment: Thanks this was the only way that i found to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know in Postgres at least you can use a cascade modifier to delete related rows.

```
DELETE FROM Categories WHERE CategoryID = 44444 CASCADE;
```